# How do I add a photo to my Ask Ubuntu profile?

Tags: discussion, support

Could someone please help me with the steps to adding a personal picture to my Ask Ubuntu profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's based on Gravatar.

All you need to do is [sign up](http://en.gravatar.com/site/signup/) with them (using the same email address you have here) and upload your image.

Comment: Should that be clearer, on the 'Registered User' edit page?